# Eclipse Logcat goes crazy

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat, android-logcat, android-debug

I was using my Eclipse Logcat crazy normally until yesterday where it started displaying messages without stop.

My message that I am printing using log.d are no longer printed to the log.
Or maybe they are but because of the huge number of messages printed they are gone.

The messages do not stop printing to the log whether I am using the app or not.
The only way to stop it is to unplug my device from the PC otherwise the messages will keep flushing to the logcat

Any suggestions ?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have no filtering of the log output and therefor sees output for every app on the phone.
Create a logcat filter with your application package name.

In the logcat window, go to "Saved filters", create a new one (if Eclipse hasn´t autocreated one for you) by clicking plus-sign to add. Type a name of your filter and write your application package name under "by Application Name". Click "ok".
When you select it you only see logcat outputs for your specified app.

Comment: Ya, works great.
It seems that I did long time ago, deleted by mistake and then forgot about it.
Thank you :)

Comment: Launching an app via eclipse usually creates a filter for you. However its not always the case. So can be done manually